# Classification models with multi-class allowed for each record

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification

I am training a multi-class classification model. `Each record can belong to one or more classes.` (actually can I still call it a classification model? or should it be a topic model or something else?)

The training data looks like this (`format_A`)

```
record_id, f_1 , f_2, f_3, ... , f_n, output_A, output_B, output_C
        1,  0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ... , 1.2,        1,        0,        1
        2,  0.3, 1.2, 0.5, ... , 2.1,        1,        0,        0
        3,  0.2, 3.2, 1.3, ... , 0.4,        1,        1,        0
        4,  1.1, 0.1, 0.7, ... , 0.5,        0,        0,        1
        5,  2.1, 0.5, 0.8, ... , 1.9,        0,        1,        1
        6,  0.5, 0.4, 0.2, ... , 0.8,        1,        1,        1
                     :
                     :
```

Right now, I am using the `sklearn logistic regression with multi-class`. I preprocess the above training data such that there is only one target per record. For record with more than 1 output, I duplicated the records. That is, the above training data becomes below (`format_B`):

```
record_id, f_1 , f_2, f_3, ... , f_n,    target
        1,  0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ... , 1.2,  output_A
        1,  0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ... , 1.2,  output_C
        2,  0.3, 1.2, 0.5, ... , 2.1,  output_A
        3,  0.2, 3.2, 1.3, ... , 0.4,  output_A
        3,  0.2, 3.2, 1.3, ... , 0.4,  output_B
        4,  1.1, 0.1, 0.7, ... , 0.5,  output_C
        5,  2.1, 0.5, 0.8, ... , 1.9,  output_B
        5,  2.1, 0.5, 0.8, ... , 1.9,  output_C
        6,  0.5, 0.4, 0.2, ... , 0.8,  output_A
        6,  0.5, 0.4, 0.2, ... , 0.8,  output_B
        6,  0.5, 0.4, 0.2, ... , 0.8,  output_C
                         :
                         :
```

I use `format_B` to train a multi-class logistic regression model. The model then predicts the probability of each category, and I set my own threshold to decide the final outputs.

While I have done the above, I am wondering would it possible to use `format_A` as the input of `sklearn logistic regression with multi-class` directly?

Or is there any package/library actually takes `format_A` as input? Or any other kind of models actually more suitable for this type of problem?

Thank you!

Comment: You might also want to look into the ClassifierChain class within sklearn.

Answer (score 2):

The task is called `multilabel` modelling. Many libraries in sklearn support this -http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html.

These algorithms generally use one vs rest strategy, building separate binary classifiers for each of the label (zero for all others) and assigning all labels which clear a probability threshold.